# How to call an activiy itself in android

Tags: android, loops, android-activity, self

Basically I am doing a quiz app, I need to dedicate one question to one page, user should be able to flip through the pages to finish one quiz. My proposed idea is to hold a singleton class for all the questions, and have an activity call itself each time for a question, and generate different content according to that question dynamically.But how would one achieve such thing? Can I use intent to call an activity itself? or should there be some other better solutions? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many questions you're talking about, the easiest way to do what you're trying to accomplish would be to load up all of your questions into Views and add them to a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). You'd only need one activity, then, and you can animate the transitions between the questions with the ViewFlipper.

Comment: By the way, why should I worry about the number of questions, is ViewFlipper only capable of handling a small amount? if so, what should be the recommend upper limit? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, if you're talking about hundreds and hundreds of questions, then there *might* be some memory issues with loading up that many views. But if you're dealing with a few dozen questions at a time, it shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would use startActivity(); or startActivityForResult(); depending on what exactly you wanted to do . Read [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)